# Given $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}, N>1,$ find integers $h,k$ with $0 < k \leq N $ that satisfy $\lvert{kx - h\rvert} < 1/N.$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

This is a problem from Apostol's $\textit{Mathematical Analysis}$. He provides a hint: Consider the $N+1$ numbers $tx-[tx]$ for $t=0,1,\ldots,N$ and show that some pair differs by at most $1/N$, where $[x]$ is defined as the greatest integer $\leq x$.

I have defined $a_t:= tx-[tx]$. I know $a_t \in [0,1)$ for every $t=0,1,2,\ldots,N$. How can I show that there exists $i,j \in \lbrace{0,1,\ldots,N\rbrace}, i \neq j$ such that $N\lvert{a_i-a_j\rvert}$ < 1? I've been stuck on this problem for a quite a while. A hint would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $N + 1$ numbers in $[0, 1)$ (one for each $t$ in $\{0, 1, \dots, N\}$). Partition the interval $[0, 1)$ into $N$ subintervals of equal length. Now consider where your $N + 1$ numbers lie with respect to this partition.

Comment: Ah, the pigeonhole principle. Thanks!